# Coordinates X237595Y81600 to X2375Y8160

Tags: linux, command-line, sed, regular-expression

I have create a gerber file and it has lines inside which look like this:

```
X90095Y15350
X100095Y15350
X110095Y15350
X120095Y15350
X120095Y25350
X110095Y25350
X100095Y25350
X90095Y25350
X80095Y25350
X160095Y25350
```

These are coordinates of the drill path - mind the **X** and **Y**. Number after the **X** and **Y** varies - it is sometimes a 6-digit and sometimes 5-digit.

---

Now I need a script which would first identify if the line starts with an **X** and then use **sed** or any other Linux tool to convert this into a format where **X** and **Y** are both 4-digits long so that line:

```
X160095Y25350
```

becomes:

```
X1600Y2535
```

Can anyone help me. I am a bit too weak in regular expressions in order to solve this myself... If there is any other command which would do this it would allso be fine.

---

**ADD**

The anwser provided is working OK and I could use it to reformat my file. After uploading it into my application I noticed that we did a wrong conversion.

I am sorry for this, but now I know what needs to be done. So If a line starts with an "X" we only have to remove the last digit of numbers after X and Y. For example if I have:

```
X90095Y15350
X100095Y15350
X110095Y15350
```

I need to get the last digit of every position (X and Y) removed:

```
X9009Y1535
X10009Y1535
X11009Y1535
```

Could someone help me with this one. =/

Comment: Oh I see... Thank you. I will edit my question then.

Comment: `sed 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)[0-9]*/\1/g'`

Comment: `awk -F'Y' -v OFS='Y' '{print substr($1,1,5), substr($2,1,4)}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed 's/\(^X[[:digit:]]\{4\}\)[[:digit:]]*\(Y[[:digit:]]\{4\}\)[[:digit:]]*/\1\2/'
```

If line starts with X (`^X`) then all digits which are **not** inside parenthesis `\(\)` are deleted.

Comment: Do you think it is not much over? If you wants to check your can do it before substitution: `/^X[0-9]*Y[0-9]*$/s ...`

Comment: @Costas I'm not sure what you are trying to say. `Number after the X and Y varies - it is sometimes a 6-digit and sometimes 5-digit` and `first identify if the line starts with an X` define the algorithm as I see it.

Comment: `sed '/^X/s/\([0-9]\{4\}\)[0-9]*/\1/g'` that is what I am told. Even you wants to include XY much simple `'/^X/s/\([XY][0-9]\{4\}\)[0-9]*/\1/g'`

Comment: Or even more close `'/^X/s/\([XY].\{4\}\)[^Y]\{1,2\}/\1/g'`

Comment: @Costas It is too simplified to my taste. For the line `XY90095Y25350` the `'/^X/s/\([XY][0-9]\{4\}\)[0-9]*/\1/g'` will return `XY9009Y2535` and `'/^X/s/\([XY].\{4\}\)[^Y]\{1,2\}/\1/g'` will return `XY900Y2535`. Both seems wrong to me.

Comment: If we told about extra check that easy to do by exchanging `/^X/` to `/^X[[:digit:]]/` and if you need you can do it stronger and stronger up to same as in my first comment.

Comment: This anwser does what it is claimed to do. But I noticed now, that I need something else - take a look at the ADD.

Comment: @71GA Try `sed 's/\(^X[[:digit:]]*\)[[:digit:]]\(Y[[:digit:]]*\)[[:digit:]]/\1\2/'`

Comment: It works like a charm. Now please help me to understand sed. Is there any sed online trainer where i can input sed commands and it will show me what it does. I found a nice one for Reg. Exp. here: http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: @71GA You may find many suggestions about `sed` tutorials here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2434/is-there-a-basic-tutorial-for-grep-awk-and-sed. Personally I use just `info sed`... And to test regex for example you can use https://www.regex101.com/