# Are there any sed scripts built in to mainstream Linux distros?

Tags: linux, sed, scripting, fhs

When I was studying `bash`, I found it very helpful to go and study the bash scripts already present on a clean install of Linux—`/etc/profile`, for instance, and anything in `/etc/rc.d/init.d/`.  These are often quite advanced scripts, and by studying them I ensured I learned about many obscure features not covered in most `bash` tutorials.

I am studying `sed` now, and although the list of `sed` features is much shorter (so I know for a fact I have studied all of the features), I still feel it would be very beneficial to study through some `sed` scripts that are actually *used* in *production*, and are not just examples in tutorials.

To that end, I would really like to study any `sed` scripts that are already present on a well-known Linux distro, such as Ubuntu or CentOS.  Trouble is, I have no idea where such scripts might be.  I've already tried `file /bin/* | grep script | sed 's/:.*//' | xargs grep sed` with no results.  `file /sbin/* | grep script | sed 's/:.*//' | xargs grep -c sed` returns some results, and I'm looking through those, but all the ones I have checked so far are just `sed` one-liners embedded in `bash` or `sh` scripts.

Where can I find some actual `sed` scripts on my Linux machine?  Or failing that, is there a good place online to find some `sed` scripts that are actually used in production?  (Reading through `sedtris` won't help much for my purposes. ;)

Comment: what you're asking for typically doesn't exist except, as you've already discovered, as one-liners in sh or bash scripts.  see also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2434/is-there-a-basic-tutorial-for-grep-awk-and-sed

Comment: I don't believe people are insane enough to write entire scripts in sed. (Not in a mainstream distro, anyway.)

Comment: ive always found sedtris edifying. if you have GNU `sed`, you can look at some of the scripts in `info sed`. you could look at [math.sed](http://www.npcguild.org/~ksb/hack/math.sed). i seriously doubt youll find any examples worth following in any scripts distributed by default with linux distributions. you would find some, though, if you looked hard at a BSD Ports tree and its constituent `make`files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
grep -w sed /etc/init.d/*
grep -w sed /etc/grub.d/*
grep -w sed /usr/bin/*
```

The first yields 25 scripts and the second 47 on my system (debian).

The `-w` option restricts `grep` to looking for `sed` as a whole word.  This way, matches to words like `used` or `supposedly` are avoided.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than look in the operating system, look at scripts used for building the programs.

Any autoconf-generated `configure` script contains sed-scripts, and itself *generates* a script which contains a sed-script.  That substitutes values for names in the template files such as `Makefile.in` to produce a `Makefile`.  For example (conveniently found with web search) this chunk of a [`config.status` file for distcc](https://opensource.apple.com/source/distcc/distcc-1702/config.status) illustrates how `sed` is used:

```
    while :; do
      case $as_dir in #(
      *\'*) as_qdir=`$as_echo "$as_dir" | sed "s/'/'\\\\\\\\''/g"`;; #'(
      *) as_qdir=$as_dir;;
      esac
      as_dirs="'$as_qdir' $as_dirs"
      as_dir=`$as_dirname -- "$as_dir" ||
$as_expr X"$as_dir" : 'X\(.*[^/]\)//*[^/][^/]*/*$' \| \
     X"$as_dir" : 'X\(//\)[^/]' \| \
     X"$as_dir" : 'X\(//\)$' \| \
     X"$as_dir" : 'X\(/\)' \| . 2>/dev/null ||
$as_echo X"$as_dir" |
    sed '/^X\(.*[^/]\)\/\/*[^/][^/]*\/*$/{
        s//\1/
        q
      }
      /^X\(\/\/\)[^/].*/{
        s//\1/
        q
      }
      /^X\(\/\/\)$/{
        s//\1/
        q
      }
      /^X\(\/\).*/{
        s//\1/
        q
      }
      s/.*/./; q'`
      test -d "$as_dir" && break
    done
```

Aside from autoconf, scripting is useful for other aspects of building (and installing) programs.  The [`manlinks.sed`](https://github.com/mirror/ncurses/blob/master/man/manlinks.sed) script in ncurses is long enough to be considered as a program.

You can of course use `grep` to find `sed` used.  However, it is common to use a ".sed" file-suffix for standalone scripts.  **`"locate .sed"`** finds those.

In a quick check on my machine, there is one extremely long sed script (more than two thousand lines, counting comments):

```
#!/usr/5bin/sed -nf
#r
#r sokoban.sed - aurlio marinho jargas <aurelio@verde666.org>
#r Changes by Gunnar Ritter, October 2002.
#r
#r Sccsid @(#)sokoban.sed       1.7 (gritter) 10/12/03
#r
#r motivated by reading the amazing Adventure (Colossal Cave) history
#r      <http://www.rickadams.org/adventure/a_history.html>
#r GPL levels took from Mike Sharpe's sokoban.vim <http://vim.sourceforge.net>
#r
#r IMPORTANT
#r this script has terminal control chars, so you must DOWNLOAD this
#r file. just copy/paste or printing it to a file (lynx) will NOT work.
#r
#r THE GAME
#r you know sokoban. everybody knows sokoban.
```

(Someone made a [colorized version](http://sed.sourceforge.net/local/games/sokoban.sed.html) of it).

That is one of three scripts used for testing `sed` in the "heirloom tools":

```
-rw-r--r--   1 tom           285 Oct  6 2002    makefile 
-rw-r--r--   1 tom          3664 Oct 11 2003    hanoi.sed
-rw-r--r--   1 tom          2338 Oct 11 2003    math.sed
-rw-r--r--   1 tom         42552 Oct 11 2003    sokoban.sed
```

Likewise, the sed program has an interesting example:

```
#!/bin/sed -nf
#  dc.sed - an arbitrary precision RPN calculator
#  Created by Greg Ubben <gsu@romulus.ncsc.mil> early 1995, late 1996
#
#  Dedicated to MAC's memory of the IBM 1620 ("CADET") computer.
#  @(#)GSU dc.sed 1.1 06-Mar-1999 [non-explanatory]
#
#  Examples:
#       sqrt(2) to 10 digits:   echo "10k 2vp" | dc.sed
#       20 factorial:           echo "[d1-d1<!*]s! 20l!xp" | dc.sed
#       sin(ln(7)):             echo "s(l(7))" | bc -c /usr/lib/lib.b | dc.sed
#       hex to base 60:         echo "60o16i 6B407.CAFE p" | dc.sed
#       tests most of dc.sed:   echo 16oAk2vp | dc.sed
#
#  To debug or analyze, give the dc Y command as input or add it to
#  embedded dc routines, or add the sed p command to the beginning of
#  the main loop or at various points in the low-level sed routines.
#  If you need to allow [|~] characters in the input, filter this
#  script through "tr '|~' '\36\37'" first (or use dc.pl).
```

Likewise, there is a page with a [colorized version of dc.sed](http://sed.sourceforge.net/local/scripts/dc.sed.html)

However, autoconf and build-scripts are where you might find productive use of `sed`.

Further reading:

- [scripts on sed.sourceforge](http://sed.sourceforge.net/#scripts)

Answer (score 0):

They are not on your machine, and they may not be used, but you could do worse than search
through this very web site you are using, e.g. [search for sed in body of answer with score of 5+](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=+is%3Aanswer+body%3Ased+score%3A5), as they correspond to real-world problems answered.