# How to remove part of a line?

Tags: string

I need to remove part of a line in a group of files.

Example line:

```
TRN*1*301444/05-13-20*6549873211~
```

I need it to be this instead (remove the portion `/05-13-20`):

```
TRN*1*301444*6549873211~
```

The forward slash up to the last asterisk need to be removed and the new line needs to be retained in the file.

Comment: you want to remove the part from `/` to `*` or the 8 characters following `/` or anything that looks like a date?

Comment: Answers you got, here's some material for learning more about `sed` and regexes: http://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/sed/info and http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2434/170373

Answer (score 3):

With `sed`:

```
sed -n 's_/[^*]*__p'
```

- `/[^*]*` matches the portion from `/` uto next `*`, and it is then replaced with null, as we have used empty string in the replacement

**Example:**

```
% sed -n 's_/[^*]*__p' <<<'TRN*1*301444/05-13-20*6549873211~'
TRN*1*301444*6549873211~
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions can be used to do that.
They are available in most languages, but [perl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/perl) is the [regex](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html) leader.
There are many ways to do what you asked with regex but here is one example;

```
perl -pi -e 's/\/.*\*/*/g' file.txt
```